# Tutorial or documentation about creating a OAuth provider in Ruby (not Rails)

Tags: ruby, oauth, oauth-provider

I am building an Ruby application using Sinatra (over Rack/Thin) and I want to implement OAuth to allow access to resources on the server. I have found [this](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/) gem, but I am now looking for documentation on actually implementing the provider -- but all I've found is a blatant lack of anything not regarding Rails.

Google was not help either. Could you point to some documentation or tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the OAuth2-provider gems? https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider and https://github.com/freerange/oauth2-provider ?

Just starting the process myself, and that's where I've seen my path heading.

Comment: I am no longer looking at this, but it looks like what I'd been wanting.